# How to print items from a list on new lines efficiently?

Tags: python, string, list, printing, splice

So I've got the following example code:

```
def example(x):
    list = [1,2,3]
    if(insert_thing):
      print(1,2,3 on new lines)
```

What I want to do is if a certain condition happens, the contents of my list will be printed on new lines. So the output of this would be:

`1
2
3`

I'm looking to do this for multiple if statements (using multiple lists depending on the if statement; i.e

```
list1 = [0,1,2] list2= [4,6,7]
if(condition):
   print(list1[0])
   print(list1[1])
   print(list1[2])
elif(condition):
   print(list2[0])....
```

and so on. How would I go about streamlining this printing of the contents on new lines into less lines? Should I make a new function (and if so, what sort of approach should I be using?)?

I'm wracking my brain to figure out a solution and am well and truly stumped; hence why I've turned to asking some other people what they might think. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If efficiency is what you wanted, you can do this by joining the list with a newline separating every item:

```
list1 = [0,1,2] 
list2= [4,6,7]
if(condition):
   print("\n".join(list(map(str,list1))))
```

Or do this which using a the print functions in Python3:

```
print(*list1, sep="\n")
```

Comment: Don't you need to convert the elements of the lists to strings before you can use `.join()`?

Comment: I forgot to mention my list is already in string format, this worked perfectly by the way. I'll bear in mind the string conversion for future (It's just str(list1) correct?) as that's something I could of easily missed. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that prints the elements of a list in a loop:

```
def printlist(l):
    for item in l:
        print(item)

if condition1:
    printlist(list1)
elif condition2:
    printlist(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [1,2,3]
if ("condition for print each element in new line"):
    for x in my_list:
        print x
if ("condition for print each element in one line"):
    print " ".join([str(x) for x in my_list])
```

I hope you want to do this only.

Comment: That's all I needed, and this was perfect. Thanks for all the answers, never realized you could print lists this way!

Comment: glad this helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use loops to print elements of a list.

```
list1 = [1,2,3]

if (condition):
    for i in list1:
        print(i)
```